# I'm trying not to make the same mistakes with foreach, but reality will not let me (Rajoy style)

Tags: php, mysql

I have learned on this page that foreach are fast, queries to the database aren't. So I'm trying to do a single UPDATE query, but it doesn't work:

```
$array = '';
foreach ($myar as $key => $value) {
  $array .= " (name='$value' WHERE lid='$key'), ";
}

$link1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE leyes SET $array");
$link1->execute();
```

I get an error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

**One solution:**

```
  $array = '';

  foreach ($myarr as $key => $value) {
      $array .= " WHEN '$key' THEN '$value' ";
  }
  $array .= " ELSE name
  END";

  $link1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET name = CASE id $array");
  $link1->execute();
```

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not a very helpful description of the problem...

Comment: If you're using prepared statements, actually __use__ prepared statements rather than building a SQL statement string

Comment: This seems not to be the correct syntax. You can have only one WHERE-clause in an UPDATE-statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd never seen this sort of syntax for an `UPDATE` before, I had to co firm my suspicion that it wouldn't work that way.  To the best of my understanding you can't use multiple WHERE clauses in an UPDATE.  You can't do what you're looking for in a single statement.

That said, there are optimization strategies you can use.  Start here:
http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-one-single-query.html

Comment: Thanks! I see this syntax in a web searching one solution :S

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$array = '';
$i = 1;
foreach ($myar as $key => $value) {
    $array .= " name='$value' WHERE lid='$key'";
    if(count($myar) != $i++)
       $srray .= ',';
}
$link1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE leyes SET $array");
$link1->execute();
```

I think you had a problem with extra ',' for the last Where statement

Comment: It does't work, same error:  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

Only add this line

```
$array = '';
foreach ($myar as $key => $value) {
  $array .= " (name='$value' WHERE lid='$key'), ";
}

//Add this
$array = substr($array, 0, -2);

$link1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE leyes SET $array");
$link1->execute();
```

Comment: This line will remove the last comma and space without needing to check a condition in each iteration